# laravel parent relationship belongsTo

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems with outputting relational data I'm trying to get the title from the producttypes class it says Trying to get property of non-object, I've tried various ways but I'm not getting the desired result

```
class Product extends \Eloquent {

    public function producttype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductTypes', 'producttype_id');
    }

}

class ProductTypes extends \Eloquent {

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany("Product", 'id');
    }
}

$product->producttype->title
```

Update

```
class ProductTypes extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['keywords', 'description', 'title', 'slug'];
    protected $table = "producttypes";

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany("Product", 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}

class ProductVariations extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = "productvariations";
    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'producttype_id', 'price', 'quantity', 'discount', 'image'];


    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}

public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::with('producttype')->findOrFail($id)->get();

    return View::make('products.show')->withProduct($product);
}
```

Show page

```
$product->producttype->title
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the database values this way

```
$product = Product::with('producttype')->get()
```

try this one.

please put this code in you routes.php file at the bottom of everything else.. just for testing purpose.

```
Route::get('/', function(){
     $product = Product::with('producttype')->get();
     dd($product);
});
```

A get() method will return result in Arrays with multiple object and firstOrfail will return only object. That's why you are getting non-object method call exception. try dd() the result set and you will know

Comment: Exactly where do I put that function, tried to put it in product class in productstypes() and I get this error Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: In product class productstypes() is a function in which you have defined your belongsTo relationship. try this in your route file I am updating my answer just for testing purpose.

Comment: I added this in the show route $product = Product::findOrFail($id)->with('producttype')->get();

Comment: $product = Product::with('producttype')->findOrFail($id); you have to do it like this

Comment: I used you're code and I'm still getting - Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that the query returns an object and not a collection. If you are using a where query you get a collection of objects unless you add ->firstorfail() to your query.
If you are using 'Model::Find(id)' then you get the object , so you can use the method.
Have a look at  [querying-relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) the red note at the end of that section.

You should try

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::Find($id);

     return View::make('products.show',['product'=>$product]); 
}
```

Then in your view product methods will be accessible

```
 $product->producttype;
 $product->productvariation //You should add this method to the product class
```